# Java: how to print a dataset of strings as entered except in reverse order?

Tags: java

This program should input a dataset of names followed by the name "END". The program should print out the list of names in the dataset in reverse order from which they were entered. What I have works, but if I entered "Bob Joe Sally Sue" it prints "euS yllaS eoJ boB" insead of "Sue Sally Joe Bob". Help!?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReverseString {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String original, reverse = "";
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a list of names, followed by END:");
    original = kb.nextLine();

    int length = original.length();


    while (!original.equalsIgnoreCase("END") ) {
        for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0 ; i-- )
        reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

        original = kb.next();
    }   

    System.out.println("Reverse of entered string is: "+reverse);

    }
}
```

Comment: Put the individual names in an array or List, then iterate backwards through the array/List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way, storing the result in the StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilber reverse = new StringBuilder();
while (!original.equalsIgnoreCase("END")) {
    reverse.append(new StringBuilder(original).reverse()).append(" ");
    original = kb.next();
}
System.out.println("Reverse: " + reverse.reverse().toString());
```

Comment: Where would I implement this into my code? What would I have to take out/edit?

Comment: Replace your ``while`` loop by this one. The only modification you might want to do is to remove the last space character.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to use this simple algorithm. Actually you're not using the proper approach.

1. Take the whole string which contains all the names separated by spaces;
2. Split it using as a delimiter the space (use the method *split*)
3. After the split operation you will get back an array. Loop through it from the end (index:array.length-1) to the starter element (1) and save those elements in another string

   ```
   public String reverseLine(String currLine) {
     String[] splittedLine = currLine.split(" ");
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");

     for(int i = splittedLine.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
          builder.append(splittedLine[i]).append(" ");               
     }

     return builder.toString();

   }
   ```

I've supposed that each lines contains all the names separated by spaces and at the end there is a string which is "END"

Answer (score 0):

Using the approach suggested in the comments above is very simple, and would look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    while (sc.hasNext())
    {
        String name = sc.next();
        if (name.equals("END"))
        {
            break;    
        }
        names.add(name);
    }

    Collections.reverse(names);

    for (String name: names)
    {
        System.out.println(name);
    }

    System.out.println("END");    
}
```

Let the Scanner extract the tokens for you, no need to do it yourself.